# Input string was not in the correct format

Tags: c#, string.format

The code below produces an error saying that my input string was not in the correct format. Why?

```
private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uriAddTagtoGroup = 
      string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AddTagtoGroup/{group}/{tag}",
                    textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);
    //line above says input string was not in the correct format?
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 string.Format("http://localhost:8000/Service/AddTagtoGroup/{0}/{1}", 
                textBox6.Text, textBox7.Text);
```

use ordinals